# Is it possible to call on a Java-method from JavaScript in Java6 1.6 script-engine?

Tags: javascript, scripting, methods, java-6

I would like to call on an own Java-method from a JavaScript-file via the ScriptEngineManager provided in Java 1.6. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/ScriptingJava.html

There are many ways of doing it. The Java code can push references to Java objects into the global context, which will look kind-of like what DOM objects look like to browser Javascript. Or Javascript can instantiate Java objects and reference them.

Comment: How exactly do I use Rhino with ScriptEngineManager? Isn't Rhink a third-party library, right?

Comment: Rhino *is* the Javascript interpreter shipped with JDK 1.6.